# Why my first row have extra space when I set a "vh"' to set the grid-row-gap instead of relative values (fr, percentage, etc.)?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Here the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-glade-7fwsm

As you will see in the stylesheet (.menu_refactor, line 91) using percentage or fr for example 
and the first row has the same space than the other rows. Using viewport height to set the spaces between rows, and the first row have extra space. Why?

Here the ReactJS snippet:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class Restaurant extends Component {
  createDish = (dishname, ingredient, price, imageSource) => {
    return (
      <div className="dish_presentation_refactor">
        <div className="dish_picture_container_refactor">
          <img
            alt="hamburger_image"
            className="dish_picture"
            src="https://tampamagazines.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/CafeDufrainSteakBurger.jpg"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="dish_data_refactor">
          <div className="dish_name_price_refactor">
            <h4 className="dish_name_refactor">{dishname}</h4>
            <p className="ingredient_refactor">{ingredient}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="dish_price_refactor">
          <p>{price}€</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  render() {
    // adding the JSX elements here
    let DishSequence = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      DishSequence.push(
        this.createDish(
          "dishname",
          "ingredient",
          "price",
          "https://cdn.radiofrance.fr/s3/cruiser-production/2019/02/3e27345f-9e1e-45bb-9e5f-906f0abb2870/1200x680_gettyimages-922684138.jpg"
        )
      );
    }

    return (
      <div className="component">
        <div className="dish_category_container">
          <h3 className="dish_category">dish_category</h3>
          <div className="menu_refactor">
            {/*implementing the JSX element in the code*/}
            {DishSequence}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here the CSS' snippet:

```
.dish_category_container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.dish_category {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.menu_refactor {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  /*grid-template-rows: 80vh; 
    grid-column-gap:3vw;
    justify-content: space-around;*/
}

.menu_refactor > div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
  background: orange;
}

.menu_refactor > div:first-of-type {
  background: lightblue;
}

.dish_picture_container_refactor {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.dish_picture {
  width: 30vw;
}

.dish_name_refactor {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #030200;
}

.dish_data_refactor {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.ingredient_refactor {
  padding: 3.5vh 0;
  color: #a37704;
  font-size: 0.7em;
}

.dish_price_refactor {
  color: #5b543c;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu_refactor {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr; /* even space between rows*/
  grid-template-rows: 80%;
  grid-template-rows: 80vh; /* uneven space between rows*/
  grid-row-gap: 10vh;
  /*justify-content: space-around;*/
}

.menu_refactor > div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60vh;
  padding: 0 3vw;
  margin: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not related to the gap but the use of `grid-template-rows: 80vh;`. This will define **one** explicit row with a height of `80vh` and all the other rows (implicit ones) will have a height auto. Since the elements inside have a height equal to `60vh` you will always have extra space in your first row and only the first row whataver the value of the gap.

To fix this you need to either remove `grid-template-rows: 80vh;` (which is useless I guess) or use `grid-auto-rows: 80vh;` to make sure all the row will have the same height.